# Overriden builtins affect live debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, overriding, built-in

I overrided `open` function, so that to bypass the file path length limitations in Windows, by providing the `\\?\` code before each path (no admin privileges to change `regedit`, and the code is distributable to multiple user, so no system changes are possible). The overriding is being done using the following:

```
import builtins
_open = builtins.open 
def override(path, *args, **kwargs):
    path += "\\\\?\\"
    return _open(*args,**kwargs)
builtins.open = override
```

Everything works as expected, **apart** from my IDE, `vscode`. For example, during debugging, all the files that open have this prefix, and no checkpoints can be added during runtime after a code pause.

I want to enable the overrides only to be considered by the functions and modules that are called inside my application and not affect the behavior of the IDE. Is something like that feasible?

### Update

An example of how vscode is affected can be seen when I open a new file from the working directory while in debugging:
[image]

Another example where open is overriden: during tests, so that the folders are [bind-mounted](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/bind-mounts-in-linux/#:%7E:text=Bind%20mounts%20in%20Linux%C2%AE,a%20jailed%20user%27s%20home%20directory) and the files are written to somewhere else, application-wide, not affecting the file system, an operation not supported by non root users. This allows for smoother integration testing.

Comment: It's unspecific. SO needs a question that can be answered with facts and citations. Anyway, here's my opinion. What about adding the prefix only when ```len(path)+1 > 260```.

Comment: Your description "for any wrapping processes" is too broad, although it's meaningless because the debugger process(VS Code) was not affected by your monkey patch. Also "any ideas ... minimal overhead" is too broad. Research more on the debugging interface(the ```pdb``` module) and ask a specific question. Also give a detailed description of your code, that justifies why the monkey patch is required on the ```open()```. Do you expect anyone can answer this question without any opinion?

Comment: "the debugger process(VS Code) was not affected by your monkey patch" . I added a screenshot :). Thank you for the feedback nonetheless, disregarding your raw manners.

Comment: Sorry if you feel so, I didn't mean it. The debugger process was not affected directly, because it is not a Python application. (It's an Electron Node.js application.) It just opened a file path, which it gathered from the debuggee process via the ```pdb``` interface.

Comment: And even if it were a Python application, it still would not be affected directly, because you didn't touch the code of the debugger process.

Comment: Aha I see, so the `pdb` exposes the path and the javascript captures it. I understand, so there is no direct manner to do what I am asking I suppose. I have only seen the issue appear when using the prefix for long path handling, so adding the path length check helped. You are welcome to add an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What about answering your own question and editing the question for specificity?

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it is more specific now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a fruitful discussion with @relent95, I understood that the IDE is never actually reading the code (it is an electronjs wrapper), and that it only reads the output from `pdb`. The case where I see this peculiar behavior occured when I clicked on the checkpoint where the application has paused. This internally queries `pdb` state and loads the file properties from there, so that it can also get the state of the debugging for that file. The file address changes however at that point for `vscode` (I think it erroneously get the file name from pdb as well), and any further additions of checkpoints to the opened file are considered to have been added to another file.

To be more specific, when the program is paused in `pdb`, the command to add a new break point is `break filename:linenum`. This is sent by `vscode` to the attached debugger. However, `pdb` (or vscode, not sure who is the culprit) converts`\\?\` windows-specific identifier to `//?/`. This causes the `pdb` to set a checkpoint to the location `//?/C:/...etc.`, which is non-existent. It does not raise an error at that point. `vscode` assumes the checkpoint addition operation was successful, and the frontend is updated, so frontend and attached process communication has broken by now.

At the end of the end, I noticed that by indeed setting a file length check to the override ensured that this behavior does not show up again. The fact that `pdb` is not a separate process or thread but directly wraps every command internally does not allow me to do any kind of check I was thinking about.

It still remains a mystery why vscode gets the obscured file name from pdb.